# Create AWS Aurora Database Schema from terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I am creating cluster instances aws_rds_cluster_instance (main.tf). Can I create schema from a file by using terraform.

```
  resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "default" {
  count                         = var.replica_count
  identifier                    = "${var.region}-${var.project}-${var.env}- 
 aurora-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier            = aws_rds_cluster.default.id
  instance_class                = var.instance_class
  engine                        = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine
  engine_version                = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine_version
  db_parameter_group_name       = aws_db_parameter_group.this.name
  preferred_maintenance_window  = "sun:02:00-sun:04:00"
  auto_minor_version_upgrade    = var.auto_minor_version_upgrade
  performance_insights_enabled  = var.performance_insights_enabled
```

Comment: You might try the PostgreSQL Terraform provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with aws provider. However you could run [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) which would call or execute a script that would create all the datatbases and tables that you need in your new aurora cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your response @marcin, I am trying with that as well but was not sure of it. Below is what I tried from my end. I am creating schema via schema.sql

Comment: ``` provisioner "file" {
      connection {
      user        = var.username
      host        = var.hostname
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/ec2_cert.pem")
    }

    source      = "./schema.sql"
    destination = "~"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      user        = var.username
      host        = var.hostname
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/ec2_cert.pem")
    }

    command = "mysql --host=${var.hostname} --port=${var.port} --user=${var.username} --password=${random_password.password.result} < ~/schema.sql"
  } ```